# jQuery UI widget missing option method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm a little confused as to why this newly minted jQuery UI Widget doesn't have an option method?

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget('ui.oTest', {
        options: {},
        _create: function(){
             $('<span>',{
                 html: 'oTest Span'
             }).appendTo(this.element);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$('.test').oTest();
$('.test').option(); //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'option'
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fwWc8/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: It's not super clear in the documentation, but options are set using the following:

```
$('.test').oTest('option', {'string': 'meow'});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/